pv fails at the exact same spot
I have attempted to copy a hard drive's contents to an image file twice and twice I have gotten pv: (stdin): read failed: Input/output error at the same number of gigabytes in. This has happened before with another (and, I think, smaller) drive (though at a different number of gigabytes in, I think). What the hell is going on?
pv is my go-to program for copying disk images. dd is way too slow, Clonezilla is too funky, and ddrescue, I've seen attested to on this network of sites, takes days to loop through its procedure on large drives.

Unfortunately that might mean the disk is failing at the spot you're getting the errors. When that happens, you should check the dmesg output: if you also see error messages referring to the disk there, it really looks like your source disk is failing.
You could use pv -E to try and skip the failing spots of the source disk, but that will leave the corresponding parts of the image file filled with zero bytes. That might be acceptable if you are just trying to rescue whatever you easily can from a failing disk, and have some more means to verify the recovered files and restore any corrupted files from somewhere else.
But if you need to try and recover as many files as you can from a failing disk, and cannot/don't want to have a professional data recovery service do it, then ddrescue would be the way to go.
